# Field 'user_id' is empty

Tags: php, database, laravel

Today I have made a comments system, but isn't completed.In my database I have all fields filled by dates, but `user_id` isn't.How can I be able to save in column `user_id`, the id of authenticated user?Here is my code.

**CommentsController:**

```
public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'username' => 'required|max:255',
            'mail' => 'required|mail|max:255',
            'comment' => 'required|min:5|max:2000',
        ));

        $post = Post::find($post_id);

        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->username = $request->username;
        $comment->email = $request->email;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->approved = true;
        $comment->post()->associate($post);

        $comment->save();

        Session::flash('message', "Message posted successfully!");
        return Redirect::back();
    }
```

**My view**

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="comment-form">
    {{ Form::open(['route' => ['comments.store', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST']) }}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
         {{ Form::label('username', "Username:") }}
        {{ Form::text('username', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         {{ Form::label('email', "Email:") }}
        {{ Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         {{ Form::label('comment', "Comment:") }}
        {{ Form::text('comment', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
      </div>
      {{ Form::submit('Add Comment', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-xs']) }}

    </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}

  </div>
```

**My route**

```
Route::post('comments/{post_id}', ['uses' => 'CommentsController@store', 'as' => 'comments.store']);
```

I tried to put `Auth::user()->id` inside my form, but I failed...

Comment: Does the `comments` table have an `user_id` column that you're trying to insert to? (Then you probably don't need the username)

Comment: Just add the `user_id` value, `$comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;` if that's what you want to add?

Comment: Thank you :) so simple, I totally forgot about that line...

Comment: thank you.So, now, in view, can I get only last 2 records from `$comment->$comment`?

Comment: Sure, just `...->orderBy('created_at')->limit(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you get the authenticated user you should only use the Auth facade. I show how to use it below.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
$user = Auth::user(); // Get the currently authenticated user...
$user_id = Auth::id(); // Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
```

Therefore, to save a user associated in a comment you have two options:

```
$user_id = Auth::id();
$comment->user_id = $user;
$comment->save();
```

Or

```
$user = Auth::user();
$comment->user = $user;
$comment->save();
```

If you have more questions about Laravel authentication take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user.

Comment: thank you.So, now, in view, can I get only last 2 records from `$comment->$comment`?

Comment: What do you would you to get? Are the last two comments?

Comment: Yeah, I want to show in my index only last 2 records from comments with view all comments button :)

Comment: Ok, you can try something like it: `Comment::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(2)->get();